# Laravel model accessors not accessible when casting models to an array or JSON

Tags: php, laravel, accessor

I'm working on Laravel project and Laravel version is 5.4. In this project I use one model called Agent with accessors to append new attribute to model as mentioned in Laravel [documenation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators).

```
class Agent extends Model
{
   //return properties for sale count
   public function getPropertiesForSaleAttribute()
   {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I can access this appended attribute directly,

```
$agent::find(1)->properties_for_sale
//result = 1
```

However when I try to access this attribute in view using vue.js (json response)

```
agent.properties_for_sale
//result = null
```

It returns null and cannot see this attribute in json response. But when I append attribute in Model as shown in below,

```
class Agent extends Model
    {
       protected $appends =[
          'properties_for_sale'
       ];

       //return properties for sale count
       public function getPropertiesForSaleAttribute()
       {
          return 1;
       }
    }
```

I can access attribute in same way and attribute available on json response,

```
agent.properties_for_sale
//result = 1
```

I cannot understand this behavior of Laravel, Why do I need to append attribute to access on json because in Laravel documentation they haven't mentioned about this.

Comment: Isn't the following sentence from the documentation enough explanation? _Occasionally, when casting models to an array or JSON, you may wish to add attributes that do not have a corresponding column in your database._ -- Your additional attribute is not stored in the database, meaning your Eloquent model doesn't hold a value for it. An accessor is only invoked on demand, finding all accessors during seriailzation would be quite costly.

Answer (score 6):

After several diggings with help of @Namoshek, here is my answer. `properties_for_sale` attribute is not originally stored in data base meaning Eloquent model does not hold a value for it. The accessor will automatically be called by Eloquent when attempting to retrieve the value of the attribute. Therefore I can access directly attribute as shown in below,

```
$agent::find(1)->properties_for_sale
//result = 1
```

According to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) when casting models to an array or JSON need to add attributes that do not have a corresponding column in database. To do this first need to define accessor for the value. After that need to add attribute name to the appends property on the model as shown below,

```
class Agent extends Model
{
  protected $appends =[
    'properties_for_sale'
  ];

  //return properties for sale count
  public function getPropertiesForSaleAttribute() {
   return 1;
  }
}
```

Once the attribute has been added to the appends list, it will be included in both the model's array and JSON representations.

Comment: It works my side.